# Given a list of names, output a list that contains only the names that consist of more than 5 characters

Tags: python

Given a list of names, output a list that contains only the names that consist of more than 5 characters.

```
names = ["David", "John", "Annabelle", "Johnathan", "Veronica"]
```

Here is my shot at this but it did not work

```
res = list(filter(lambda x: len(str(names[x] > 5, (names)))))
```

I'm getting the error

```
    res = list(filter(lambda x: len(str(names[x] > 5, (names)))))
TypeError: filter expected 2 arguments, got 1
```

Comment: The answer to this question is very simple, you have not researched enough

Comment: tried lambda with function filter

Comment: Ok if you have tried that show that.

Comment: res = list(filter(lambda x: len(str(names[x] > 5, (names)))))

Comment: @KyryloIershov That's almost correct. Try `list(filter(lambda x: len(x) > 5, names))`.

Answer (score 0):

Using a **list comprehension** :

```
more_than_five = [item for item in names if len(item) > 5]
```

Maybe practice converting this list comprehension into a for-loop... or attempt your own solution

Answer (score -1):

Logic for list comprehension:

```
#for everyname in names
#if everyname is greater than 5
#add everyname to list
```

Logic for dict comprehension and dict comprehension

```
#create dictionary
#for everyname in names
#add name as key and length of that name as value
#iterate through that dicts items
#check if value is greater than 5
#if so append key to list
```

Here is an example using the logic of dict comprehension and dict comprehension from above.

```
names = ["David", "John", "Annabelle", "Johnathan", "Veronica"]
count = {name:len(name) for name in names}
newNames = [k for k,v in count.items() if v > 5]
```

Here is an example using logic of list comprehension from above

```
names = ["David", "John", "Annabelle", "Johnathan", "Veronica"]
newNames = [name for name in names if len(name) > 5]
```

Comment: Why use a dictionary comprehension for processing a list?

Comment: This can be useful for the OP later on.